# SQL with Optional Parameters. When parameters are populated we need to use LIKE operator, otherwise return all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

We have a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wo_hdr 
WHERE tm_no LIKE CONCAT('%', $P{tm_no}, '%')
```

However when the parameter `$P{tm_no}` is null we need to return all values.

I have seen others use

```
SELECT * 
FROM wo_hdr 
WHERE tm_no is null or tm_no LIKE CONCAT('%', $P{tm_no}, '%')
```

This does not work for us because then when we don't want to return null values when `$P{tm_no}` is not null.

Does anyone know a good solution for this? I thought possibly a CASE statement would work but it looked confusing to use one in the WHERE clause. It needs to work with both ORACLE and SQL Server.

Thank You.

Comment: You got it wrong. It is not "where tm_no is null", it is where your parameter is null.

Comment: BTW a better control for this is to do this check directly on the front end.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your `where` clause with :

```
SELECT * 
FROM wo_hdr 
WHERE ($P{tm_no} IS NULL OR tm_no LIKE CONCAT('%', $P{tm_no}, '%'));
```